# Spinner How to set an unique style in different versions?

Tags: android, textview, spinner, adapter

I have an app which works in android 2.2.x or superior , in 2.2.x the spinner is look like this (the spinners are inside in the red box):

A1 .- Spinners in the beginning
[image: ...]

A2 .- Spinner when I select Región field (that change the data in Comuna field)
[image]

But in 4.x or superior look like this:

B1 .- Spinner in the beginnig
[image]

B2 .- Spinner when I select Región field
[image]

I need that in version 2.2, it looks the same as in version 4.x , in white text and Align to the left (In the xml options, I selected left)

I use this style:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/TextView01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:text="@+id/TextView01"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

for both spinners and I use with this dropdown:
      android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item

Can you help me how to set this?

Comment: your xml is for a TextView, and your question is about a Spinner... did you post the right code snippet?

Comment: In example (which saw it here, but do not remember the link), recommend use textView for change the text color and size, then you use like this:  new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.spinner_text,dataArray);

Comment: Now, if you know the correct way to do this, please show me how